# Android : How to get images from webserver(mysql) with relative-path?

Tags: android, mysql, image, webserver, relative-path

I already know how to use PHP+MySQL to get the URL path of image and turn it to a bitmap in android. But now I want to get the images from another way. If the image is stored by relative-path in MySQL, how can I turn it to a bitmap?
Are there any tutorials or demos?